# install libraries and dependencies with .sh file python ([Errno 26] Text file busy)

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install all required files an libraries to raspberry pi with a .sh file. Here is my sh

```
#!/bin/sh
#installer.sh
cd /
sudo mkdir /home/pi/Scripts/rclient
sudo pip install signalr-client
sudo pip install signalrcore
sudo apt install libffi-dev
sudo pip install cffi
sudo pip install aenum
sudo pip install requests-toolbelt
sudo python2 -m pip install PyMySQL
cd /home/pi/Scripts
sudo tar xfv agent-service.tar
cd /home/pi/Desktop/service
sudo mkdir /home/pi/.config/autostart
echo "
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=launcher.sh
Exec=/home/pi/Scripts/service/launcher.sh
" >>/home/pi/.config/autostart/service.desktop
sudo chmod +x /home/pi/Scripts/service/launcher.sh
sudo chmod +x /home/pi/Scripts/service/open_script.sh
sudo chmod +x /home/pi/Scripts/service/service
sudo mkdir /home/pi/Scripts/f
```

I make this file executable with: `sudo chmod +x installer.sh`

and call it from my python script: `os.system("/home/pi/Scripts/installer.sh")`

But I got **[Errno 26] Text file busy** error.

Is there something wrong about my .sh file? Or it is my py script? I could not understand.

Answer (score 0):

Run `lsof /home/pi/Scripts/installer.sh` or `fuser /home/pi/Scripts/installer.sh` to check what process it using the file that cause it busy.

Then kill the process to release the file.

Comment: I did what you said and  it seems like my python program (that I use to call installer.sh) is using installer.sh. Something is wrong. Here is my python code:
```fn=('installer.sh')
file=open(fn,'wb')
savedir= '/home/pi/Scripts/'
os.chdir(savedir)
os.system('sudo chmod +x /home/pi/Scripts/installer.sh')
os.system("/home/pi/Scripts/installer.sh")```

Answer (score 0):

The message ‘[Errno 26] Text file busy’ will occur when trying to update a binary program that is currently executing (or a shared library .so). Most likely, the ‘tar’ command.

Assuming the tar is unpacking a binary, consider removing ‘/home/pi/Scripts/rclient’ and or other binaries (executables, shared libraries) before unpacking the tar file.

You might also consider adding ‘set -x’ to find out which exact line produce the error, the the problem is not with the tar. If you identify a single file, you can remove or rename it before installing the new version.